# Deploying nodes after upgrading my CorDapp to Corda V3 fails with java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Tags: corda

Deploying nodes after upgrading my CorDapp to Corda V3 fails with java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper.bootstrap(java.nio.file.Path)

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the Corda Gradle plugin version to 3.0.9 in the build.gradle file fixes the issue.